# In emacs' find-file, is it possible to remove ./ and ../ from possible completions for faster tab completions?

Tags: emacs

We have a large project that for whatever reason has lots of nested directories that often have just one other nested subdirectory in them such as

```
perl-thing/lib/PACKAGE/SUBPACKAGE/X.txt
```

In the terminal it's easy to navigate through this as I just hit tab a bunch of times and eventually it auto completes to X.txt as it's the only object in SUBPACKAGE.

In Emacs though, using find-file, I have to hit p then tab to get perl-thing, then l-tab for lib, P-tab for PACKAGE etc, which slows down getting to X.txt. This seems to be due to find-file listing ./ and ../ as possible completion along with the lone subdirectory.

Is it possible to remove the ./ and ../ completion candidates such that I can move through the directory list structure quickly with tab? Or should I be using something other than find-file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use write your own `read-file-name`-function which ignores `./` and `../` and set it as the default, like this:

```
(defun read-file-name-nodots (prompt &optional dir default-filename mustmatch initial predicate)
  "Like read-file-name-default but does not complete on ./ and ../"
  (let ((predicate (or predicate (lambda (f) (not (or (string= f "./") (string= f "../")))))))
    (read-file-name-default prompt dir default-filename mustmatch initial predicate)))
(setq read-file-name-function 'read-file-name-nodots)
```

Comment: Ah super helpful on how to reset read-file-name-function.  Unfortunately it proves my assumption wrong, even without the . and .. , find-file doesn't descend into the only sub directory the way shell does when tab is pressed.

Comment: Hmm, you could perhaps try adding an advice to `file-name-all-completions` but it might not work very well since it's a built-in function. Or maybe trying ``completion-file-name-table``.